# Blocking Application from being Executed

Tags: .net

Ihave a C function which blockes exe applications from being Executed, and i like to do the same with window form .net2. How?

```
int ExecuteBlocking(const char *appName, const char *cmdLine)
{
 char sz[260];
 STARTUPINFO siStartupInfo;
 PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo;
 memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo));
 memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo));
 siStartupInfo.cb = sizeof(siStartupInfo);
 BOOL b = CreateProcess(0, sz, 0, 0, 0, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE, 0, 0, &siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo);
 if (b == 0)
  return -1;
 WaitForSingleObject(piProcessInfo.hProcess, -1);
 CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hProcess);
 CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hThread);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: On what stage do you want to block the execution of the program? After it started? Before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That C code does *not* prevent a program from executing.  It simply waits for it to finish executing, the function won't return until that happens.  You'd get the exact same thing in .NET with Process.WaitForExit().

Comment: oops i have upload the wrong function, please let me update the question, but anyway how to blocking application from being executed in net2

Comment: Please don't update the question.  I gave you a good answer to your original question, it behooves you to mark it answered and start another one.